# Why am I getting free(): invalid pointer error?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, free

I'm writing a program which generates arrays with different properties and different sizes, bubble-sorts them, counting comparisons and swaps number, and prints the result for each sequence and each size. Program prints result until "case 2, n = 20", and then terminates with "free(): invalid pointer" error. I'm really struggling to understand, why.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void generate_sequences (int **a, int n, int var)
{
    *a = (int*) malloc (n * sizeof(int));
    if (*a == NULL) {
        printf("memalloc fail\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    switch (var)
    {
        case 1:
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                (*a)[i] = i + 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            for (int i = 0, j = n; i < n, j >= 0; i++, j--)
                (*a)[i] = j;
            break;
        case 3:
            for (int i = 0, j = n; i < n, j >= 0; i++, j--)
                (*a)[i] = (i%2 == 0)? i + 1 : j;
            break;
        case 4:
            srand(time(NULL));
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                (*a)[i] = 1 + rand() % n;
            break;
        default:
            printf("invalid var\n");
            return;
    }
}

int compares = 0;
int swaps = 0;

bool compare (int x, int y)
{
    compares++;
    return x >= y;
}

void swap (int *x, int *y)
{
    swaps++;
    *x ^= *y;
    *y ^= *x;
    *x ^= *y;
}


void bubble_sort (int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            if (compare(a[j], a[j + 1])) 
                swap(&a[j], &a[j + 1]);
}

int arith_mean (int *a, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += a[i];
    sum /= n;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int sizes[] = {10, 20, 50, 100};
    int *comps_num = calloc(4, sizeof(int));
    int *swaps_num = calloc(4, sizeof(int));
    int *a;
    for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
    {
        printf("-------- case %d --------\n", j);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            generate_sequences (&a, sizes[i], j);
            bubble_sort (a, sizes[i]);
            comps_num[i] = compares;
            swaps_num[i] = swaps;
            printf("n = %d:\n", sizes[i]);
            printf("comparisons = %d\n", compares);
            printf("swaps = %d\n", swaps);
            compares = 0;
            swaps = 0;
            free(a);
        }
        printf("average comps = %d\n", arith_mean(comps_num, 4));
        printf("average swaps = %d\n", arith_mean(swaps_num, 4));
    }
    free(comps_num);
    free(swaps_num);
    return 0;
}
```

It's really weird for me that code prints some result before terminating. I supposed maybe it has something to do with incorrect memory allocation inside generating sequences function, but the corresponding check inside this func is not met, which means that this is not the case

Comment: This immediately looks suspect: `for (int i = 0, j = n; i < n, j >= 0; i++, j--)`. You have a comma operator in the middle part of the `for` statement. Which means the left-hand side of it is discarded, and only the right-hand side is evaluated.

Comment: Buffer overflow leading to memory corruption seems most likely. https://godbolt.org/z/5joYnvjfh

Comment: @pmacfarlane That is weird, although it seems like `i < n` and `j >= 0` should be equivalent tests.

Comment: @Barmar I guess so. It's smelly though.

Comment: Yes, they almost certainly meant `&&` rather than `,`

Comment: I'm feeling really stupid rn, but yeah, the problem was in that comma. Thanks for answers

Comment: I guess they're not equivalent, probably an off-by-1 difference.

Comment: I'll add that there's no reason for the loop condition to depend on `j` at all. They don't want `i < n && j >= 0`. Simply `i < n` is what they want.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `,` with a `&&` in the `case 2` and `case 3` loops.  After this change I can no longer elicit any issues with `free()`.  As noted by @pmacfarlane you can simplify the loop condition to just `i < n` as `i` goes from 0 to `n - 1` (`n` iterations), and `j` goes from `n` to `0` (`n+1` iterations which is probably a off-by-one error masked by the condition on `i < n` condition).

Moved the `srand(time(NULL));` as you don't need to reset it, arguably it could be incorrect (you only get a new seed once per second), and you want a central place to control it so you can record the one seed and possible set it to an explicit value to reproduce an issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void generate_sequences (int **a, int n, int var)
{
    *a = (int*) malloc (n * sizeof(int));
    if (*a == NULL) {
        printf("memalloc fail\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    switch (var) {
        case 1:
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                (*a)[i] = i + 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            for (int i = 0, j = n; i < n && j >= 0; i++, j--)
                (*a)[i] = j;
            break;
        case 3:
            for (int i = 0, j = n; i < n && j >= 0; i++, j--)
                (*a)[i] = (i%2 == 0)? i + 1 : j;
            break;
        case 4:
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                (*a)[i] = 1 + rand() % n;
            break;
        default:
            printf("invalid var\n");
            return;
    }
}

int compares = 0;
int swaps = 0;

bool compare (int x, int y)
{
    compares++;
    return x >= y;
}

void swap (int *x, int *y)
{
    swaps++;
    *x ^= *y;
    *y ^= *x;
    *x ^= *y;
}


void bubble_sort (int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            if (compare(a[j], a[j + 1]))
                swap(&a[j], &a[j + 1]);
}

int arith_mean (int *a, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += a[i];
    sum /= n;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int sizes[] = {10, 20, 50, 100};
    int *comps_num = calloc(4, sizeof(int));
    int *swaps_num = calloc(4, sizeof(int));
    int *a;
    for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
        printf("-------- case %d --------\n", j);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            generate_sequences (&a, sizes[i], j);
            bubble_sort (a, sizes[i]);
            comps_num[i] = compares;
            swaps_num[i] = swaps;
            printf("n = %d:\n", sizes[i]);
            printf("comparisons = %d\n", compares);
            printf("swaps = %d\n", swaps);
            compares = 0;
            swaps = 0;
            free(a);
        }
        printf("average comps = %d\n", arith_mean(comps_num, 4));
        printf("average swaps = %d\n", arith_mean(swaps_num, 4));
    }
    free(comps_num);
    free(swaps_num);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is a sample session:

```
-------- case 1 --------
n = 10:
comparisons = 45
swaps = 0
n = 20:
comparisons = 190
swaps = 0
n = 50:
comparisons = 1225
swaps = 0
n = 100:
comparisons = 4950
swaps = 0
average comps = 1602
average swaps = 0
-------- case 2 --------
n = 10:
comparisons = 45
swaps = 45
n = 20:
comparisons = 190
swaps = 190
n = 50:
comparisons = 1225
swaps = 1225
n = 100:
comparisons = 4950
swaps = 4950
average comps = 1602
average swaps = 1602
-------- case 3 --------
n = 10:
comparisons = 45
swaps = 29
n = 20:
comparisons = 190
swaps = 120
n = 50:
comparisons = 1225
swaps = 769
n = 100:
comparisons = 4950
swaps = 3100
average comps = 1602
average swaps = 1004
-------- case 4 --------
n = 10:
comparisons = 45
swaps = 27
n = 20:
comparisons = 190
swaps = 129
n = 50:
comparisons = 1225
swaps = 772
n = 100:
comparisons = 4950
swaps = 3196
average comps = 1602
average swaps = 1031
```